# How to make SQL Server 2012 delete expired records and check on a daily basis

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am new to SQL Server and am learning. I have a monthly `Membership` table and a `DateTime` column called `Expiration`.

What do I have to look into so that I can make my SQL Server 2012 check for expired records on a daily basis and delete them records. I know that SQL Server has this functionality was just wondering what is it called and do you have any suggestions or tips on creating something like this..

Comment: First thing is to create a stored procedure to do the work. Make sure all date checks are done against getdate(). Then you create a sql job to execute your newly created procedure as frequently as makes sense.

Comment: You might want to ask yourself whether deleting expired records is really a good idea.   You will lose your ability to look up historical data.   If you have an expired date, you can simply filter on that date when you want to retrieve only current records.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I will implement both.

Comment: Just as an observation. Many systems I've worked on over the years have been written without the ability to expire records but the intent to add this feature. This feature rarely gets added to these systems. About the only thing that consistently gets expired in my experience is processing and transaction logs.

Comment: What edition of SQL Server are you using? Pretty much anything but Express has the SQL Agent which you can use to schedule the execution of SQL code.

Answer (score 2):

You could start by creating a procedure as below:

```
USE [DatabaseName]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_ProcedureName] ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ProcedureName]
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @expirationdatetime datetime;

SET @expirationdatetime = getdate()

BEGIN
    DELETE FROM [TableName]
    WHERE Expiration < @expirationdatetime

END
```

Once you have created the proc, you will want to go to the bottom of your object explorer where you will see an option **SQL Server Agent**. Under that, you will see another tab **Jobs**. Right click on it and click on New Job... option. You should see the following screen:

[image: New Job Screen]

Next go to Steps on the right side, click on New... On the new screen, type in your step name and leave the default type as **Transact-SQL script(T-SQL)**.

[image: New_Job_Step]

Next go to Schedules and click on New... to add your schedule to run your new stored procedure daily.

[image: Create new schedule]

Hopefully this should get you to what you need!